# Corman insertion sort in php not working

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

Algorithm

```
for k from 2 to n
  key = a[k]
  j = k - 1

  while (j > 0 and key > a[j])
    a[j + 1] = a[j]
    j = j - 1
  end while

  a[j + 1] = key
end for
```

my code:

```php
function insertionSort(array $array) {

    $length=count($array);
    for ($i=1;$i<$length;$i++) {
        $element=$array[$i];
        $j=$i-1;
        while($j>0 && $array[$j]>$element) {

            $array[$j+1]=$array[$j];
            $j=$j-1;
            }

        $array[$j+1]=$element;
        }
    return $array;
}
```

output:

```
Array (
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 1
)
```

What am I doing wrong here, why is the first element not sorted?

Comment: `while($j>0 && $array[$j]>$element) {`.... perhaps `while($j>=0 && $array[$j]>$element) {`

Comment: Awesome , Thank you. I was so stupid to not notice that.

Answer (score -1):

Hey please check the second condition of your wile loop in your algorithm and your PHP code, it may help you...